How to modify a custom attribute of Cognito Userpool?
I have made application which requires login and signup. The data fields of users are like (name, emailid, password and role_type(default is visitor). So there are two roles- Admin and visitor. I have a page called UserManagement, where I can change the type of user from admin to visitor or vice versa. I did this previously by storing the user data in a Database and modifying the role of that user via a typical API request. Now, recently, I shifted to AWS Cognito for storing and managing all users. I had a name, email and password as usual, and for role I had to make a custom attribute called role (custom:role like this), and then I could have all the same parameters as previously. Now I want to know how I can display all users and also change their custom:role type attribute from visitor to admin and vice versa using Cognito from UI. Do I need to implement an API for handling this or do you guys have any other ideas on this?
I think, by default, Cognito doesn't allow changing attributes of other users.
Any Ideas or Suggestions are Appreciated.
This is how my signup looks like for reference
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { toast, Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { useNavigate, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserPool from './UserPool';

const Signup = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSignup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      toast.error('Passwords do not match');
      return;
    }

    try {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        UserPool.signUp(
          email,
          password,
          [
            { Name: 'name', Value: name },
            { Name: 'email', Value: email },
            { Name: 'custom:role', Value: 'admin' }
          ],
          null,
          (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data);
          }
        );
      });

      toast.success('Signup successful. Please check your email for the confirmation code.', {
        duration: 3000,
        onClose: () => navigate('/confirm-email'),
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      toast.error(err.message || 'An error occurred. Please try again.');
    }
  };

And this is how my UserPool looks like:
import { CognitoUserPool } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import { cognito_user_pool_id , cognito_client_id  } from "../utils/config";

const poolData = {
  UserPoolId: cognito_user_pool_id,
  ClientId: cognito_client_id,
};

export default new CognitoUserPool(poolData);


Apporch 1: using frontEnd
user attributes are updated directly from the frontend using AWS Amplify's Auth module, which retrieves the current authenticated user and updates their attributes asynchronously. This approach is straightforward and allows real-time updates but requires proper handling of authentication and error management on the client side.
async function updateUserAttribute(attributeKey: string, value: string) {
  try {
    // Get the current authenticated user
    const currentUser = await Auth.getCurrentUser();
    // Update the user attribute
    const result = await Auth.updateUserAttributes(currentUser, {
      [attributeKey]: value,
    });

    // Check if the update was successful
    console.log(`Successfully updated ${attributeKey} to ${value}.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating user attribute:", error);
  }
}


updateUserAttribute("custom:myCustomAttribute", "New Value");


Apporch 2: using CKD python (much easier)
leverages AWS Lambda and Python's Boto3 SDK to update user attributes programmatically. The Lambda function receives a request body, extracts the user's email and attributes, and calls admin_update_user_attributes. This server-side approach simplifies attribute updates by managing them in one place, but it requires IAM permissions to ensure secure access to the Cognito User Pool
def update_user(body):
    data = json.loads(body)
    email = data.get("email")
    attributes_to_update = data.get("attributes", {})

    user_attributes = []
    for key, value in attributes_to_update.items():
        user_attributes.append({"Name": key, "Value": value})

    try:
        cognito_client.admin_update_user_attributes(
            UserPoolId=user_pool_id, Username=email, UserAttributes=user_attributes
        )
        return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps("User updated successfully")}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"statusCode": 500, "body": json.dumps(str(e))}

Note:

To execute the admin_update_user_attributes function, the Lambda
function must have permission to perform this action on the specified
Cognito User Pool. This requires the following IAM policy
permissions:


